# Gets number of rows but doesn't print

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a program written in `Swift 3`, that grabs `JSON` from a `REST` api and appends it to a table view.

Right now, I'm having troubles with getting it to print in my `Tableview`, but it does however understand my count function.

So, I guess my data is here, but it just doesn't return them correctly:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, HomeModelProtocal {

@IBOutlet weak var listTableView: UITableView!


func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {
    feedItems = items
    self.listTableView.reloadData()
}

var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
var selectedLocation : Parsexml = Parsexml()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.listTableView.delegate = self
    self.listTableView.dataSource = self

    let homeModel = HomeModel()
    homeModel.delegate = self
    homeModel.downloadItems()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier: String = "BasicCell"
    let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
    let item: Parsexml = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! Parsexml
    myCell.textLabel!.text = item.title

    return myCell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return feedItems.count 
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


}
```

Are you by any chance able to see the error that I can't see?

Note. I have not added any textlabel to the tablerow, but I guess that there shouldn't be added one, when its custom?

Comment: myCell.textLabel!.text = item[indexpath.row]

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: no, its not :( Thank you for your answer though. 
It tells me that Type 'parsexml' has no subscript members

Comment: you are welcome,please print your feed item first...

Comment: They are all nil :O - They really shouldn't be. Where might i have gone wrong?

Comment: i mean. it understands that i have 100 rows in my JSON API

Comment: Are you saying that if you print `feedItems.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection` it is 100 but if you print `item` in `cellForRow` it is nil?

Comment: It was nil yes.. i ran through my code again! and i figured that i made a typo in my setter. doh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

  print(yourArrayName.count) // in your case it should be like this print(feedItems.count)
}
```